# Nearest spiral barred galaxy undergoing interaction

Tags: galaxy

Which is the nearest spiral barred galaxy undergoing interaction, other than M31 (Andromeda) and our own Milky Way galaxy?

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely NGC 55, which is interacting weakly with NGC 300.  NGC 55 is described as a Magellanic type barred spiral galaxy.

This answer assumes that you ignore the Large Magellenic Cloud itself, which is a barred spiral galaxy and is interacting with the Milky Way.

Comment: Another possible candidate is M33, which is more of a classical spiral galaxy than the LMC, though not everyone is sure it's barred.